# Programmatically Creating ObservableArrays with Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm working on a project where my model's fields (names and quantity of) won't be known until runtime and should be added dynamically after the data is retrieved.  I'm trying to create a generic viewModel where the fields will be added to the viewModel and hydrated, so developers working down stream can just work within the views.

For example, my data may look like this:

```
// Retrieved data 
{
    "partner_category_str": [
        "Financials",
        "HCM",
        "Payroll",
        "Technology"
    ],
    "partner_program_str": [
        "Certified Solution Partner",
        "Cloud Connect Partner",
        "Connect Partner",
        "Solution Partner"
    ]
}
```

My quasi-generic viewModel that populates itself with properties from the retrieved data:

```
function Facet (data) {
    this.name = ko.observable(data);
};

function SearchViewModel () {
    var self = this;

    $.getJSON("/partners_api/?requestType=facets&partnerType=Software+Partner", function (facets) {
        var facet = null,
            facetData = null;

        for (facet in facets) {
            facetData = ko.utils.arrayMap(facets[facet], function(facetItem) { return new Facet (facetItem);});
            self[facet] = ko.observableArray(facetData);
        }
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new SearchViewModel());
```

And I'd like the Web developer to be able to use the viewModel data in their views (They'll know the field name when they create the view) like so:

```
<!-- View -->
<!-- Note: the bound field name comes directly from the retrieved data -->
<select id="partner_category_str" data-bind="foreach: partner_category_str">
    <option data-bind="text: name, value: name"></option>
</select>
```

On these dynamically created fields, the data is not being bound to the views, but viewing the data with `data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"` shows the properties are set on the viewModel. It appears my data is being lost in translation somewhere, but I'm not sure where.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [mapping plug-in](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) for knockout.  It will dynamically create the knockout observables from the json coming from the server.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to mark this correct! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I face a similar situation at work.

You haven't given enough details for me to give a full answer, but I can put you in the right direction.

First: `observableArray` is your friend.  I find using a template to display an array far more reliable then using the `if` binding, even if that array only holds element.

So, off the cuff, something like this.

```
var vm = {
  // Whatever

  myObjectArray: ko.observableArray();
};


// I'm using Durandal, so I get this nice method when a view is loaded.   
function activate(/* view, parent */) {
 // When the view is activated...

 var myObject = {
   firstName: ko.observable(),
   lastName:  ko.observable()
 };

  vm.myObjectArray.removeAll();
  vm.myObjectArray(myObject);
```

}